# python: how to add column to record array in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, records

I am trying to add a column to a numpy record.

This is my code:

```
import numpy
import numpy.lib.recfunctions
data=[[20140101,'a'],[20140102,'b'],[20140103,'c']]
data_array=numpy.array(data)
data_dtype=[('date',int),('type','|S1')]
data_rec=numpy.core.records.array(list(tuple(data_array.transpose())), dtype=data_dtype)
data_rec.date
data_rec.type

#Here, i will just try to make another field called copy_date that is a copy of the date    , just as an example

y=numpy.lib.recfunctions.append_fields(data_rec,'copy_date',data_rec.date,dtypes=data_rec.date.dtype,usemask=False)
```

Now look at the output

```
>>> type(y)
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
>>> y.date
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'date'
>>> y.copy_date
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'copy_date'
```

y is no longer a type of record like

```
>>> type(data_rec)
<class 'numpy.core.records.recarray'>
```

I seem to have lost the record abilities, which is to call the fields by the attribute.
How can I correctly add a column to a record and be able to call the fields?

Also, I'd be happy if someone can tell me what the usemask option does in the above code.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass `asrecarray=True` to get a recarray back out of `numpy.lib.recfunctions.append_fields`.

e.g.:

```
>>> y = numpy.lib.recfunctions.append_fields(data_rec, 'copy_date', data_rec.date, dtypes=data_rec.date.dtype, usemask=False, asrecarray=True)
>>> y.date
array([2, 2, 2])
>>> y
rec.array([(2, 'a', 2), (2, 'b', 2), (2, 'c', 2)], 
      dtype=[('date', '<i8'), ('type', '|S1'), ('copy_date', '<i8')])
>>> y.copy_date
array([2, 2, 2])
```

*Tested on numpy 1.6.1*