# How to define dictionary structure in ndarray

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, multidimensional-array

I want to create a 3 dimensional array with each value in the array represents a dictionary.

For example: `myArray[m][n][k]` of type `{'position':(0,0), 'boundary': [(8,8)(512,512)]}`

I know that, it could be defined by specifying `dtype` parameter in `numpy.ndarray`

```
numpy.ndarray(shape=(m, n, k), dtype=...)
```

What should be the `dtype` to specify the exact dictionary syntax as above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK there is none. The best you can do is define `dtype = object` (which is what you'll get if you try setting `dtype=dict`, for example) - and then populate it manually. Nothing will ensure the structure ("syntax", as you call it) of the dictionary - you can use a class for that.

*However*, please note that numpy is optimized for scalar variables and your usage is very odd.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need named columns and the column set is immutable, you can use record arrays:

```
In [30]: arr = np.zeros((3,3), dtype=[('position', 'f8', 2),
                                      ('boundary', 'i8', (2,2))]); arr
Out[30]: 
array([[([0.0, 0.0], [[0, 0], [0, 0]]), ([0.0, 0.0], [[0, 0], [0, 0]]),
        ([0.0, 0.0], [[0, 0], [0, 0]])],
       [([0.0, 0.0], [[0, 0], [0, 0]]), ([0.0, 0.0], [[0, 0], [0, 0]]),
        ([0.0, 0.0], [[0, 0], [0, 0]])],
       [([0.0, 0.0], [[0, 0], [0, 0]]), ([0.0, 0.0], [[0, 0], [0, 0]]),
        ([0.0, 0.0], [[0, 0], [0, 0]])]], 
      dtype=[('position', '<f8', (2,)), ('boundary', '<i8', (2, 2))])

In [31]: arr['boundary'][0] = [[1,2], [3,4]]

In [32]: arr
Out[32]: 
array([[([0.0, 0.0], [[1, 2], [3, 4]]), ([0.0, 0.0], [[1, 2], [3, 4]]),
        ([0.0, 0.0], [[1, 2], [3, 4]])],
       [([0.0, 0.0], [[0, 0], [0, 0]]), ([0.0, 0.0], [[0, 0], [0, 0]]),
        ([0.0, 0.0], [[0, 0], [0, 0]])],
       [([0.0, 0.0], [[0, 0], [0, 0]]), ([0.0, 0.0], [[0, 0], [0, 0]]),
        ([0.0, 0.0], [[0, 0], [0, 0]])]], 
      dtype=[('position', '<f8', (2,)), ('boundary', '<i8', (2, 2))])
```

Comment: The answer is really helpful. Is there a way that, I could add a named column (say `('visited', 'i8', 2)`) of no fixed size (initially empty array), and it could be appended later. Example `[[1,0],[2,0],[1,2],...]`

Comment: You could use `append_fields`, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24867747/python-how-to-add-column-to-record-array-in-numpy).